# Windows 7 virtualenv envl AssertionError and OSError

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, setuptools

AssertionError: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\PKG-INFO is not a subpath of C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg\virtualenv_support\setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl\

OSError: Command D:\myproject2\envl\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip failed with error code 1

How can I fix the AssertionError and OSError?

I tried "activate", but it doesn't work.
 I know activate.bat file didn't exist... 
 I think it is because of these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today. Although not possibly the best answer, here's what I did:

1. Completely uninstalled all previous Python versions. *(I had 64bit versions of both 2.7 and 3.2 already installed, plus a 32bit version of 2.7)*
2. Removed any remaining files in the python install path(s).
3. Restarted. (Just in case)
4. Re-installed python.
5. Followed the non-chocolatey version of https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/ exactly. (aka I didn't install pip via easy_install, but instead downloaded the get-pip.py file as explained in the guide)
6. Run `which virtualenv` to check that virtualenv is installed and being pulled from the correct location. (If not, add the path to you python install to you `PATH` environment variable, removing any other python paths)

Now when I try `virtualenv --no-site-packages <packagename>`, it works!